# @Inject annotation not working

Tags: java, jboss, cdi

I'm trying to use CDI for the first time.  While I have successfully injected one EJB inside another using @EJB, I can't get the @Inject annotation to work.

```
@Stateless
public class AccountDaoImpl implements AccountDAO {

    @Inject
    private MultiTenantEntityManagerImpl mtem; //always null

}
```

And the multi-tenancy entity manager looks like this:

```
 @Default
public class MultiTenantEntityManagerImpl {
   .....
}
```

I've created a beans.xml file (empty) but and shoehorned it into the META-INF folder in the built jar file. Still no joy.

I'm sure it's something simple.  I'm running in jboss 5.0.1.GA.

### Update

So it looks like the @Inject annotation is not supported in jboss 5.

An alternative is to use the @EJB annotation, but this isn't working either:

```
@Stateless
public class AccountDaoImpl implements AccountDAO {

    @EJB
    private MultiTenantEntityManager mtem; //still null!

}
```

Weirdly, in another EJB, this exact declaration of the entity manager is working fine.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, CDI is part of Java EE 6 which is not supported by jboss 5.0.1.GA.

Comment: Which version of java ee are you using?

Comment: aargh!  So I've been banging my head against a brick wall this whole time.  What are my options?

Comment: You could use Spring or Guice for the injection and just rely on EJB for Services, Remoting and transactions ... but this migth get messy so its probably best to just use a latest version.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i was missing subsystem in the standalone

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, in jboss 5 at least, an @EJB annotation will only be respected if **both** the following conditions hold:

1. The class in which you're using it is an EJB
2. The class is retrieved from the container somehow (eg JNDI), rather than being simply instantiated via a constructor.